# Foreach Loop MultiTab Import by Month

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an Excel file that I get from a vendor. The file has multiple worksheets in it all labeled by Month (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc). Each month a new worksheet is added for the previous months Data (I receive the data in March but the Excel file will have a worksheet for Jan and Feb).

I have used the Foreach Loop container to grab files, rename them and drop them into other folders. But what I want to do is set up a dynamic Foreach Loop that will read the data on the newly added worksheet in the file. So far all I can find is how to run through all of the worksheets at one time (incrementally), but I don't want to grab any of the previous data, only the newly added sheet.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished.

(note: I am pretty good at working in SSIS but complex Expressions and Script Tasks still through me from time to time.)

Comment: Maybe you can check the name of the sheet to see if it equals the current month or is after the current month before evaluating the sheet. Or you can select the last sheet in the workbook if the most recent sheet is always at the end

Comment: Either of these options would work. I unfortunately, don't know how to accomplish this task. I have been scouring the internet looking for a solution but everything I find leads to reading ALL of the worksheets, not just the newest one.

Comment: Could you show the code that you've used currently to loop through all the sheets?

Comment: I followed this http://www.sqllion.com/2009/06/programming-foreach-loop-container-%E2%80%93-enumerating-excel-sheets/

Comment: Apologies, I'm now realizing you're doing the foreach loop from ssis and not excel (vba). I'm not familiar with SSIS.